# Cortana Skill authentication on invocation not working

Tags: oauth, cortana, cortana-skills-kit, cortana-invoke

I have a fully working Cortana Skill, and I tried to include Oauth authentication by following this link:

[Configure authentication for Microsoft's identity server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/configure-connected-account)

But it's not working, it's just not showing anything and allowing the user to use the skill with no authentication. Besides the configuration in the link above, is there any code that I need to implement in the bot service? I would appreciate your help.

Thanks!

**Update 1**

This is how I've setup the Cortana Oauth details, right now using the example from the Microsoft article:

[image: Cortana Oauth setup]

As far as I understand, nothing else should be done in code for the login request to show up, only the piece of code to retrieve the auth token, but nothing shows up, the Skill starts to run right away.

I've tried using authentication with GetTokenDialog and SendOAuthCardAsync and it works, however by the time that I receive the confirmation code to finish the authentication, if I say it to Cortana, "she" does not recognize the code, and if I type it instead, it works but Cortana stops talking.

I also followed this video, and it's exactly what I've done:

[Build 2017 Authentication in Cortana Skills](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ToW8ECsaHTs)

Do I need to update the botBuilder SDK or something? I'm at 3.15.2.2. I just never get the login prompt. Thanks!

**SOLUTION**

It turns to be a Microsoft bug; since everything was ok, I decided to delete the Cortana channel and re-create it from scratch and now the login prompt is showing up, thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bot oauth and cortana oauth work slightly different.

First, make sure you have turned on "Cortana should manage my user's identity" on the Cortana channel configuration via azure portal or botframework.  Then fill in all the fields (we are updating the website doc immanently because it is incorrect). Don't select "Sign in when required" unless you send an OAuth card before your resource call.

Then when you invoke your skill the OAuth dialog should be shown.  If it isn't, don't forget Cortana will cache your auth token if you successfully logged in once.  You can clear the token by disconnecting the skill via the Cortana notebook.

I have samples in node and c#.  https://github.com/bw-kforce-ms/CortanaSkillsWIP/tree/master/Consumer/Node/OAuth2Example

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/authentication is closer to "as built". However, like mentioned, there are some updates coming up shortly. Feel free to ask for clarification here.

Comment: Thanks!, I checked the sample in the link, and whenever I hit the "sign-in" button created using OAuthCard, nothing happens. The connection is setup and working (created under Oauth Settings in the bot settings) because I've tested it using GetTokenDialog and SendOAuthCardAsync, but both of them returns a code that I must type in or Cortana does not recognize it, and if I type it, then it works but Cortana stops talking, that is why I'm looking for other options.

Comment: The OAuth data under bot settings is NOT used for Cortana. Its misleading - I know. You need to turn on the "connected services" from the Cortana channel config to use OAuth.  If an OAuth card is sent to cortana, you should only ever see it if there is no token. Cortana won't speak the oauth card - it is fully handled via the canvas.  If you use an Invoke, it will ask you to login on a desktop or mobile device.

Comment: I updated my original question; I read your last comment and I kind of understand that by just setting up the Cortana Oauth fields it should be enough, but no matter how many times I invoke my skill by saying "Open [Skill name]" no prompt is shown and it works right away.

Comment: Dump the auth token from the entities.  If there is no auth token, its a config issue (and you can email a screenshot of the config from both the channel config AND app registration to skillsup at microsoft dot com.) If there IS an auth token, then go to the cortana notebook and disconnect the skill. That should clear the auth token. Another way to change that up is to change the invocation name and phrase.

Comment: By checking several code samples, articles and forums my problem is that Cortana is not prompting the login screen after the invocation is made and I already disconnected the skill from the user; could that be considered a bug?